# Introduction to Memory Addresses and Data Types

Tags: c, memory-address

I was reading through some papers on Memory Addresses and Data Types in the C language and I've been grasping the content pretty well but I stumbled upon some maths and I can't seem to figure it out anywhere on the Internet.

Suppose I create two local variables

```
void foo(void){
    int i, j;
    printf("int i is stored in %p\n", &i);
    printf("int j is stored in %p\n", &j);
}
```

The output I get is

```
int i is stored in 0x6ffc88
int j is stored in 0x6ffc84
```

And in the text I'm reading, an integer is of size 4 bytes (same with my computer). So, `int i` is supposed to be allocated 4 bytes. But the difference between `int i` and `int j`'s memory address is just 4 bits (`0100`).

Is the difference not meant to be something greater, like 4 bytes (`0xffffffff`)?

Please where am I making the confusion?

Comment: 'difference between int i and int j's memory address is just 4 bits' - no, those are byte addresses.

Comment: Addresses are byte addresses.  C does not allow bit addressing.

Comment: Most of CPUs are Byte addressable. C can speak to CPU and request Memory read/write operation that is perform in Bytes not bit. with C we can read/write Memory location at least byte by byte although after reading and put it on in an integer variable we can do bit manipulation on it with these >> << & | bits operators

Comment: On most modern 32 *and* 64 bit platforms `int` is 32 bits. I.e. four bytes.

Answer (score 6):

j is located at at BYTE addresses 0x6ffc84,0x6ffc85,0x6ffc86,0x6ffc87, so, 32 bits.

i is located at at BYTE addresses 0x6ffc88,0x6ffc89,0x6ffc8a,0x6ffc8b, so, 32 bits.

Apart from microcontroller horrors like 8051, modern non-trivial processor architectures don't have bit addressable memory.